# Javascript Variable Scope Confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, scope

In the following code snippet I've declared the variable "id" within the submit function. I attempt to assign a value to it within a nested function but it doesn't appear to be within scope and I don't know why.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if (typeof(localStorage) == 'undefined' ) {
    alert('Your browser does not support HTML5 localStorage. Try upgrading.');
} 
else {

    $("#logForm").submit(function(){
        var id;

        chrome.bookmarks.getRecent(1, function(mostrecent) {
            getLastId(mostrecent);
            });

        function getLastId(mostrecent) {
            mostrecent.forEach(function(mostrecent) {
                lastId = mostrecent.id;
                alert(lastId + ' was last id');
                id = lastId;
                })
            }
        alert(id + ' outside function');
```

Bonus Question - If you know a better way to pull the last-used id from chrome for a bookmark would love to know what it is. I had to pull recent which doesn't account for the possibility of an added and then deleted last bookmark which would have incremented the index.

Comment: @ Šime - Is there a lint for ECMA 5?

Comment: JSLint is for EcmaScript 5, too.

Comment: You forgot to declare the `lastId` variable.

Comment: missing semicolon on the forEach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$("#logForm").submit(function() {

    var id;

    chrome.bookmarks.getRecent(1, function(arr) {
        id = arr.pop().id;
    });

    // do stuff with id

});
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing that. I'm struggling with the asynchronous functions required by the chrome api quite a bit. Do you know how to verify the value assignment has been made before attempting to use the variable?

Comment: @Korak If the callback is asynchronous, you have to continue your code inside the callback body. If the callback is synchronous, your can continue your code below the callback. So it depends...

Comment: @Šime Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way somehow. My goal is to get the id on the last node from the chrome bookmarks api which requires the usage of an asynchronous function. Is there a better way to assign, pass, or return that value than what I am doing?

Comment: @Šime just thought I would post to let you know that I've been able to move enough of the action inside the function to make it work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Šime Thanks a lot for all your help. Will be dealing with these issues on an ongoing basis so your answer will help with a bunch of variable extractions.

Comment: I think that whether the callback is asynchronous or not, you should not write code that depends on code inside the callback function.

Comment: @JuanMendes Synchronous callbacks are fine, and it is not an issue if the subsequent code depends on it. For instance `var results = arr.map( function () { ... } );` and then work with `results`...

Comment: @Korak you may want to look up closures. Based on your response, it appears that you think that this syntax implies an asynchronous call.  However, closures can be synchronous, as in this case, or passed as callbacks asynchronously.  That may help some of your syntax confusion.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I did think about that case... I meant to say something more like: "If you need a value that is set from a callback". In cases like what you mentioned, you don't depend on any values that were set from the inner function.